# Android - What could be the ways in which once app starts it wait for tasks to be performed and exits after that?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-camera

I was wondering how about the different ways in which an app can be opened, some tasks performed on the main thread and then be finished. And which way would be the best for this purpose. 
I thought using an asynctask and putting the thread to sleep for sometime should be helpful and in postexecute perform the task that i want. But I am pretty sure this is a very expensive solution.

For example, If I want the app to click a photo on its own when the app is opened. The app needs to be opened and then wait so that the camera resources can be loaded properly. Once this is done the photo is clicked and once the photo is saved the app will finish.

Please provide some links if you can so I can read up and understand these concept better.

What are the better ways to go about solving this problem than using thread.sleep()..

Please share any good methods..

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why would you want the app to take a picture unless you are talking about screenshots but even then I'm not sure it makes sense to me. Depending on exactly what you are going for, Async might work or you could use a service.

Comment: What i need from the app is that it opens clicks a photo and closes.. I have implemented a camera app. i am trying to capture the picture in oncreate and once the photo is saved i am finishing the activity. But I am unable to do this. The app opens and just remains doesn't capture the photo and doesn't exit..

Comment: You might like to read here for sleeping: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html and here for waking up: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you need (I'm not sure) you can use broadcast to cominicate between tasks

Comment: What i need from the app is that it opens clicks a photo and closes.. I have implemented a camera app. i am trying to capture the picture in oncreate and once the photo is saved i am finishing the activity. But I am unable to do this. The app opens and just remains doesn't capture the photo and doesn't exit..

Comment: @kulPrins Are we to guess what your onCreate() looks like?